# Calling member function through a null pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I was wondering how concepts lite could be implemented in the language. After some digging in boost/concept's headers I came across this struct:

```
template <class Model>
struct user_requirements 
{
    ~user_requirements() { ((Model*)0)->~Model(); }
}
```

I thought that calling a member function through a null pointer is undefined behavior. Even if the destructor doesn't use any member variables, should this be relied on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will go horribly wrong if `~Model` is virtual.

Comment: calling a member function through a null pointer **is** undefined behavior